# Why isn’t $f:\!R \rightarrow P : a \rightarrow ax^3 + a^2x^5$ a linear operator?

Tags: linear-transformations

Why isn’t $f:\!R \rightarrow P : a \rightarrow ax^3 + a^2x^5$ a linear operator?

Because $0 = 0$ and in my understanding it is closed in linear combinations. Isn’t it?

Comment: What is $R$ and $P$?

Comment: For things like this to have a chance of working you need to be working over a Boolean Ring (if you want a vector space instead of just a module, you obviously want a *field* of characteristic zero)

Answer (score 3):

Simply because $f(a+b) \neq f(a)+f(b)$.

$$f(a+b)=(a+b)x^3+(a+b)^2x^5=(a+b)x^3+(a^2+2ab+b^2)x^5$$
while
$$f(a)+f(b)=ax^3+a^2x^5+bx^3+b^2x^5=(a+b)x^3+(a^2+b^2)x^5$$

And they are different unless $ab=0$ i.e. $a=0$ or $b=0$

Answer (score 1):

We have that in general

$$f(a_1+a_2)\neq f(a_1)+f(a_2)$$

For example, try with $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1$ that is

$$f(1-1)=f(0)=0 \neq f(1)+f(-1)=2x^5$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  For $f$ to be linear you must have $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b$. Here $f(1)+f(1)\neq f(1+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that, in general:

$$f(ab) \ne af(b),$$

(take $a=b=2$, for example),

hence, $f$ is not linear